# Apache Spark UDF - Why User Defined Function returning wrong value

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

**Question**: It seems I'm not doing something right in the following code when I'm calling a `User Defined Function (UDF)`. Why the output is not "This is a test"?

**Remark**: I'm using `python notebook in` Azure Databricks`.

**Notebook cell1**:

```
def TestFunction(myVal):
  return "this is a " + myVal
```

**Notebook cell2**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,DateType,StringType

new_name = F.udf(TestFunction, StringType())

s = new_name("test")

print(s)
```

**Output**:

```
Column<'TestFunction(test)'>
```

**Desired Output**:

```
This is a test
```

Comment: use the `new_test()` as a pyspark function within a `select()` or `withColumn()`. it returns a column with the desired value(s)

Comment: You need to pass a column name into this udf. And then the values of the column will be used inside udf. The result will be a column.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, example in Scala

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import spark.implicits._
val new_name = udf((myVal: String) => { "this is a " + myVal })

val df = Seq(
  (1, "test1"),
  (2, "test2"),
  (3, "test3"),
  (4, "test4"),
  (5, "test5")
).toDF("id", "name")

val res = df.withColumn("new_name", new_name(col("name")))

res.show(false)
//    +---+-----+---------------+
//    |id |name |new_name       |
//    +---+-----+---------------+
//    |1  |test1|this is a test1|
//    |2  |test2|this is a test2|
//    |3  |test3|this is a test3|
//    |4  |test4|this is a test4|
//    |5  |test5|this is a test5|
//    +---+-----+---------------+
```

Comment: I don't know Scala. But my upvote (+1) for your Scala example.

Answer (score 0):

User defined functions (UDF) are meant to be used along with Dataframe columns where they perform a certain function on DataFrame columns.

- Here `TestFunction()` expects string argument and returns concatenated string output (`"this is a " + myVal`).
- When a UDF is created using `new_name = F.udf(TestFunction, StringType())`, the new_name UDF does not work similar to a normal function `TestFunction()`

```
s1 = new_name("test")
print(type(s1))
#<class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>

s2 = TestFunction("test")
print(type(s2),s2)
#<class 'str'> this is a test
```

- The desired output can be achieved **using a regular function**, but while using UDF (*passing string as argument instead of column*) it returns `pyspark.sql.column.Column`.
- Therefore, the proper way to use **UDF is with a dataframe column** where it applies the operations on all the rows of column/columns. For example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[['test']],schema=['col1'])
df.show()

#output
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|test|
+----+
```

- Using UDF:

```
df.withColumn('col2', new_name(df['col1'])).show()

#output
+----+--------------+
|col1|          col2|
+----+--------------+
|test|this is a test|
+----+--------------+
```

Refer this [official spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) to understand about `udf()`